# Perfect powers of the form $2^n\pm n$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, perfect-powers

In the range $$1\le n\le 10^5$$ the only perfect powers of the form $$2^n\pm n$$ are $$2^5-5=3^3$$ and $$2^7-7=11^2$$

> How can I prove that there are no more perfect powers of this form ?

The case of even $n$ allows at least to find the possible perfect squares, but I do not have an idea for a complete solution.

Comment: I feel nothing leads one to think that there are no more solutions. Nothing prevents us from believing in the possibility of even an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: FWIW, Mathematica is unable to find an instance where $2^n+n$ is a perfect power.

Comment: I can't get an argument for $n$ odd, but if $n$ is even, then $2^{n}$ is a perfect square, and the next closest squares are
$$(2^{n/2} \pm 1)^{2} = 2^{n} + 1 \pm 2^{n/2+1}. $$
which is too large a gap for $n \ge 3$ I think.

Comment: It's intuitively clear the the "defect" between $2^{2k-1}$ and the closest squares expands by "about" a factor of 4 each time, but I don't think it's exact and don't have a good bound.

Comment: If n is prime, then $2^n-n ≡2 \mod (n)=nk+2$. The generating function $n k +2$ may give infinitely many perfect powers, for example with n=7; for k=17 we get $121= 11^2$ or for k=2  we get $36=6^2$.

Comment: We have that $2^1 - 1 = 1$ is a perfect power, so the range should be $1 < n \le 10^5.$ Generalizing from the comment by @preferred_anon, I don't think it's too hard to show that if $2^n \pm n = m^k,$ then $n$ and $k$ must be relatively prime.

Comment: @TedHopp $1$ is usually not considered to be a perfect power. The usual definition is $a^b$ for some integers $a,b>1$

Comment: While 1 is usually not considered a perfect power, sometimes it is (as is 0). If you mean to exclude it, why specify the range of $n$ to include 1 in the question?